# Tomcat Bayeux Support / Tomcat Modules

Tags: java, svn, tomcat

It seems that Tomcat has [in the current trunk a module for Bayeux support](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/modules/). But this is not included in [the current stable branch](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_7_0_12/).

What is the Tomcat development process? Will Bayeux Support be included in the next version? What exactly does the "Modules" directory in the trunk mean? Is this just a playground that will never get into the final release or will the projects under modules later be incorporated into the final releases? Why is it not in the final release - it seems that it is present for quite a long time there?

Does anyone have know if this implementation is stable?

Is it possible to download this module somewhere? It seems it is not contained in the standard jars (at least not by this obvious name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With tomcat 7 I believe you're best to look at the built in [comet support](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/aio.html), although it seems to handle the more generic case of comet rather than the specific bayeux protocol.  The bayeux code you point too looks pretty bitrotted:

```
$ svn log http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/modules/bayeux/
```

But you could simply check it out and build it (from a bash shell):

```
$ svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/ tomcat7
$ cd tomcat7/modules/bayeux
$ ant
```

unfortunately you'll need to check out all of tomcat7, as the antfile refers to files two levels above it in the root project directory.

FWIW, my company evaluated using the tomcat bayeux support (with tomcat6), and ended up going with cometd (which supports bayeux) on Jetty, partially because its being actively developed and has an active user community.  Since tomcat7 supports the servlet 3 spec, you should be able to deploy cometd on top of tomcat7, but I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Hello Bobby Powers, thanks so much for your help!!!! Your hint with cometd.org is absolute great! I already read about it, but I didnt know its a servlet spec 3 compatible application/war that can simply be deployed on any servlet 3 api container. this really solves the problem. (what a pitty that tomcat7 as the leading app server does not officially support byeux, and even worse it does neither support websockets.websockets will be the future. Jetty also supports websockets. so I already also thought about migrationg to jetty. But I will try cometd now. thanks very much!!!